# Woocommerce customer role doesn't change if user is already a subscriber

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users, user-roles

I noticed the following behavior on woocommerce :

I have a user on my website who is already registered with 'subscriber' role.

When I login and checkout on my woocommerce shop, user role still remains on 'subscriber' and role is not updated to 'customer'.

Problem is on admin page (Users > All users) : when I use the filter to show all customers, users who were already subscribers and have made orders don't appear on search results.

I use Wordpress 4.9.6 et Woocommerce 3.3.3.

Can anybody explain to me if this behavior is all right ?

Thank you.

Comment: which plugin do you use to manage suscribers ?

Comment: @Kaperto i don't use plugin to manage suscribers, I created a test user with admin panel.

Comment: to change the role, you need a plugin like that : https://woofrance.fr/forums/topic/abonnements-avec-subscriptions-probleme-du-role-des-abonnes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While WC is off topic, and I am not going to dig into how it explicitly works, in general wordpress roles are just a semantic way to call a class of permissions and users probably can not belong to two roles at once (this is an observation based on user management UI, not on whether it is possible to somehow hack something in the DB or via code), therefor if the user already exists it is just not obvious what to do if it might be better assigned to some other role. Not surprising that if a customer of a shop is already a user on the site, WC does not modify it in any way.

So this is not so much about wrong and right but more about you looking for information about customers in an admin screen that is meant to manage user permissions and other non shopping related attributes

Comment: Thank you @Mark Kaplun for your answer, I posted topic on woocommerce support forum.